# asp.net breadcrumb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, navigationcontroller, sitemappath, web.sitemap

I am having a problem with the breadcrumbs - when I use the breadcrumb to move back in the breadcrumb to the previous node in the sitemappath control is there way to store the data.

is there a way around this?

thanks

Comment: If you press the Back button of the browser, the data will still be there.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that is possible with default sitemap because each node is a link that simply redirects. You will have to either customized the sitemap with may be buttons and handle click event and store info in session and also keep track of user navigation. This might turn out to be a complex structure.

OR may be developing your own breadcrum like sitemap :(

Comment: okay that doesn't sound like a route i want to go down or could do :S do you think this is something that is expected/requirement of a SiteMapPath control?

Comment: Yes. That is the expected behavior of SiteMapPath of not retaining the values.